# Scaling Docker Containers Question with .Net Core Worker Services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core, containers

I have a fairly what I think is simple question but am completely unfamiliar with design considerations when using docker containers. So I have been trying to come up with a structure for an app that should have 1 UI (Im thinking MVC at this point), but multiple worker services.

**My Question:**

If I have 1 UI app, and lets say 4 worker services each in their own docker container, each using SignalR. How do I go about structuring/determining the URL to call my SignalR hubs for each container?

Essentially I would like to be able to scale the worker service portion from 4, 5, 6, etc. We have these boxes that we need to communicate to which I will call "Controllers", and I would like to have 1 worker service per "Controller" and add / remove docker containers to match the number of "Controllers" we have running in the shop. How does one organize / determine the url structures so it is consistent whether I remove or add containers?

End goal is to send data from my UI with SignalR to the individual containers which then transfers that data/commands to the controllers live.

**Other Info:**

We plan on running this with a red hat Linux VM.

**Picture To Kind of Explain:**

[image]

Any advice / direction would be greatly appreciated as I am pretty new to docker containers and SignalR. Not sure if I am even approaching this problem correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: are you running on azure or on a different provider?,

Comment: @Isparia My company wants us to run this on a Red Hat Linux VM.

Comment: the problem with signalR is, in your architecture, that you need a controller which connects your hubs to your users. On azure there is a service for that, but everywhere else you are pretty much out of luck

Comment: @Isparia Well I will be using MVC for our front end so I can use that controller to access the SignalR hubs contained in the worker service and use the MVC controllers as the SignalR clients (If I am understanding what your saying correctly)

Comment: This might help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

Comment: @Alexander I think that is more of a scaling out across multiple servers which I highly doubt with this app we will ever need to do. I am just more curious on how do you "know" / "Configure" your endpoints from the UI side? There some way to query the docker container names, would this be part of a CI / Deployment lifecycle settings? If I named the SignalR hubs something like Hub/{ControllerName} Would the URL be something like https://RedHatServer/Hub/Controller1 ..... https://RedHatServer/Hub/Controller2 when calling the SignalR hubs? I almost feel I should be containerizing the ui side.

Comment: Are Worker Services 1-4 and controllers 1-4 different services or is it just many instances of the same service?

Comment: @Alexander it is many instances of the same service and THAT is exactly what I am struggling with. I have no idea how to I guess determine the number of instances I have currently running from my UI? Or how I would go about mapping those http requests. Essentially each instance of the worker is tied to a specific Box (Upper portion), I think in my mvc backend I would simply build out the url string like https:// RedHatServer/MyService1/Hub/{Controller}? The worker service needs to keep a constant multiple network sockets open to a specific upper level box.

Comment: @Alexander I would like to dynamically add new worker service/box combinations on the fly. Those boxes control some wifi torque tools for us. So when a line worker/client sends: Set torque to 10ft/lbs, it NEEDS to go to the controller attached to their tool. Our production lines go up and down often so today I may have 3 boxes to control tools, tomorrow I could have 5, I need to spin up instances of that worker service each tied to a specific box while enabling the client to talk to a specific one...if that all makes sense.

Comment: In my understanding if you go with 1 UI for multiple worker services you'd need to implement logic for discovering running workers and displaying set of these urls on your UI so user can choose what worker he configures. But it's way easier to just bundle UI with worker in a container so it always works with its *own* worker. But in this case user need to know which url to type to access specific UI.

Comment: @Alexander I think having separate urls for each service would be acceptable.. We could set that as their default page on their computer/tablets appropriately. From what I read it is typically better to separate containers for your UI and individual services. We will never have a scaling issue with the UI, so I assume it should be okay to wrap both the UI and the worker service in a single container? Could you point me to some documentation or examples that could get me going the right direction. FYI Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes, you typically don't put UI together with the backed to container because you need to scale only backend side and in this case it doesn't matter to which container request goes because all of them will perform the same action for any given request. But for some reason you need to ensure that request goes to a specific container (I still don't understand it fully) so I suggested it will be easier to put UI with its worker service in one container. What kind of examples/documentation are you interested in?

Comment: And to answer this question **How does one organize / determine the url structures so it is consistent whether I remove or add containers?** it would be good to know how `Controller`s and containers are added, automatically or manually? And how ulrs and ports are assigned to containers etc.

Comment: @Alexander On the top 4 blocks (Controller 1, Controller2, Controller3,etc.) it probably would have been better to name those Device1, Device2, Device3, etc. So we do have to set up the devices physically. However I would like to make deployment of a new service that connects to that device to be fairly automated most likely with Azure Dev Ops (Installed on local server not Azure). So Each device has its own IP address. So basically I need to make sure the request from the users UI gets sent to the right device which sets the torque on the users tool they have in their hand.

Comment: @Alexander as far as how urls and ports are assigned to the containers is up in the air at this point. I don't know what the best practice is as far as that. Again I prefer everything to be pretty automatic. So if I add a new device on our production line, I would like to deploy a new instance of worker, in the container, for that device (which has its own specific IP address which I am not even sure the best place to store that or inject it?)